# PHP-curl prints result instead of returning it

Tags: php

So my problem is that I am sending a `curl` request to a website and it's always printing the HTML response, for example:

```
<html><header>Example</header></html>
```

This is how I executed my curl:

```
$output = curl_exec($ch)
```

I did not echo out `$output` but it constantly returns the value over and over again.

Comment: Are you sure you don't print it? What's the code around this line – conditions, loops?

Comment: It's just curling to the website normally and nothing else. I don't echo anything.

Comment: Make sure you learn the difference between outputting and returning values.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`:

> **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: TRUE** to return the transfer as a string of the return value of
>   [curl_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) instead of outputting it out directly.

You can do this with [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) (quote above from this doc):

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true )
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Currently, I am trying to fetch string using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to true. But, instead of resulting result.. it is returning empty array. Do you have any suggestion please?